# MildWild rom stuck?

Tags: htc-desire, custom-roms, rom-flashing

I've just installed the new MildWild (oxygen) rom http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1353861, to replace my very old LeeDroid rom.

It's seemed to have installed fine, but when the phone boots, I get the 'mildwild' logo on screen, just animating for ages, nothing seems to happen.

Is this a problem with the install? I cleared all my partitions, cache, dalvik, etc, and ClockWork didn't report any errors.

Anyone have any ideas? Or shall I just try a different rom? I'm working with a UK HTC Desire (bravo)

Comment: How long did you wait? It must be rebuilding dalvik cache.

Comment: I gave it about 10 minutes. Should I wait longer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually can happen with any ROM you install.

If you are not installing a "new" version of the same ROM, you can get in to a boot loop. You have to do a factory reset and clear the data and cache when installing a new ROM for the first time.

If you are installing an upgraded version of the ROM, you don't have to do the wipe (unless the instructions tell you that you should). But you should always clear the cache.

When the device boots up for the first time, after clearing the cache, it needs to rebuild the cache for the applications you have installed. The more applications that you have installed, the longer it will take to boot the first time.

Keep an eye on the "boot up", if it looks like it is "starting over" and not just replaying the boot animation, you are in a boot loop. If you have adb installed, you can plug the device in and look at the logcat that is going on during the boot process. This can also help you determine if you are in a loop or not.

Answer (score 0):

I had not done a factory reset. Once I had done this, it took about 2 minutes to boot up!